# How does DefaultHandler work?

Tags: java, android

I am playing with Android and RSS and in the part of the XML parser we have the DefaultHandler with its methods:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) 

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
```

And the characters.

Now I went through the documentation, but it doesn't really gives a deep insight, how are the method being exactly executed, also how are those arguments `localName` , `qName`, etc being exactly passed? I see in the code examples they just initialize the class, but where they put the variables.
Also how do we defined the which elements to look for in the `startElement` method, like Title , Description etc, I see different examples looking for different strings, does this mean that we have to have a beforehand look at the XML from the URL, or is there a firm standard for the tags used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DefaultHandler is a callback that gets called by the XML parser. Different methods of DefaultHandler are called in different situations. For example, the method startElement() is called whenever the XML parser encounters a start of an element. In the following XML document:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>XML</title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Java</title>
  </book>
</books>
```

the method startElement() will be called when the XML parser parses "<books>", "<book>", and "<title>". The parameters passed to the method startElement() contains details information about the read element. For example, the parameter "localName" contains the name of the element (i.e., "books", "book", and "title").

You can look at the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) for more details on the situations where the methods are called, and the descriptions of the parameters.